# How can I browse my previous Mac Time Machine Backup?

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore

I did move from an iMac to a Mac Mini and I did use the same TM disk but I did not restore from TM backup since I was moving from intel to M1

When I connect the backup TM ask me if I want to inherit previous backup and I said YES

I can see on the right hand side older bars from when I started backing up the Mac mini but I don't know how to access them

Comment: As you deleted the old backup and have not yet do TM backup, there is nothing yet to look in backup. Wait until some backup are done.

Comment: I did not delete anything, I had the same file structure on iMac that was backupped on that TM disk. I'm sure it is possible to see iMac backup I did several years ago and I could see in finder which disk I want to access but I don't remember hot to enable this thing.

Comment: you did not restored from TM , this may be the cause.

Comment: Look at [this page](https://mactakeawaydata.com/restore-files-from-time-machine-to-another-mac/) seems to have some tips that may help you.